# Django tables not updating column data

Tags: django, tabular, django-tables2

I'm trying to pull data from mongodb and display it as a table in display.html page.

My data from table looks  something like this:

```
[{u'Subjects': u'[Sub1, Sub2, Sub3, Sub4]', u'Student Name': u'A'}, {u'Subjects': u'[Sub2, Sub12, Sub7, Sub9]', u'Student Name': u'B'},{u'Subjects': u'[Sub1, Sub2, Sub14]', u'Student Name': u'AC'},
```

Below is my code:

views.py

```
def data_list():
    dis_data = db_data.find()
    table = DataTable(list(dis_data))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'app/dispaly.html', {'table': table})
```

My tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class DataTable(tables.Table):
       Names = tables.Column(verbose_name = "Student Name")
       Subjects = tables.Column()
```

display.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

<div>
{% render_table table %}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when displaying its only displaying subjects but not Student Name. Where is it going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the [accessor](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/internal.html?highlight=accessor#django_tables2.columns.BoundColumn.accessor) in your Table Class's `Name` column:

```
class DataTable(tables.Table):
       Names = tables.Column(verbose_name = "Student Name", accessor="Student Name")  # <-- Here
       Subjects = tables.Column()
```

Comment: that worked !! Adding "accessor" . guess it was not taking spacee?

Comment: Yes, so you needed `accessor` to access that key of the dictionary.

Comment: Ruddra not sure if i can ask here. If i want a bootstrap table  what are all the changes to be added

Comment: I think you can look into this: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html